# Where compare values between tables

Tags: mysql, select

Objective: I have 3 tables each with the same field names. I want to add to a 4th table the values from the 3th table if the sales value passes certain conditions.
Something like :

```
INSERT INTO table4 (int, den, prod, sales, ut, stoc)
SELECT int, den, prod, sales, ut, stoc FROM table3 
WHERE (0 < table1.sales) AND (table1.sales < table2.sales) \
       AND (table2.sales < table3.sales)
```

Thanks

Comment: do you get any error or warning? what is your doubt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO table4 (`int`, den, prod, sales, ut, stoc)
SELECT T3.`int`, T3.den, T3.prod, T3.sales, T3.ut, T3.stoc 
FROM table3 T3 INNER JOIN table1 T1 ON (T1.sales > 0)
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON (T1.sales < T2.sales) AND (T2.sales < T3.sales)
```

Comment: I am getting closer. I get #1052 - Column 'int' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @vingnesh when you use join then prefer is to use `.` operator. Btw why do you suggest this? do you have any objection in OP query?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan because join is good option here.and without knowing table schema i can't mention . operator right..

Comment: After a loading message that lasted forever the phpMyAdmin somehow broke and doesn`t let me log back in #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server